Is it possible to stop WebView2 creating user data files and folders?
I'm looking into whether WebView2 would be a better alternative to the existing implementation of WebBrowser2 in my Email Client application (because WebBrowser2 is limited in rendering and javascript support).
I've got WebView2 up and running in an ordinary Win32 window.  The code is here.  It's actually an implementation in assembler, which I find easier to use than other programming tools.  In this case assembler offered a very simple implementation of WebView2 using the WebView2Loader.dll.
I understand that I can load WebView2 dynamically with an html string, and when the user needs to edit the html, the application will be able to use the DOM and/or javascript to do this and download the result, in the same way as I currently have WebBrowser2 working.
My problem however, is that WebView2 creates a number of user data folders on the local machine, under the folder EBWebView.  I can see that it is possible to change the location of these folders, but in my application which would merely use WebView2 to render html content in an email and allow it to be edited, there is no need for the user data folders at all.
Is it possible to stop WebView2 from creating user data files and folders?
I have looked in vain for a way to stop WebView2 from creating and filling the user data files and folders when it is running.

Me too! For me, it causes issues syncing to cloud.
